# local variable referenced before assignment - token confirmation

Tags: python, flask, itsdangerous

I have a Flask API where I'm confirming accounts on registration. Itsdangerous is used to generate a token which I email to the user. Upon clicking the token, the API checks that the token is valid and checks that the email address of the user exists. When I click the link in the email I get the following error:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'email' referenced before assignment
```

If I hard code the email in the confirmation endpoint function, it works perfectly. Not sure where I'm going wrong.

This is the code that sends the confirmation email:

```
def send_confirmation_email(user_email):
  confirm_serializer = URLSafeTimedSerializer(app.config['SECRET_KEY'])

  confirm_url = url_for(
    'users.confirm_email',
    token=confirm_serializer.dumps(user_email, salt='email-confirmation-salt'),
    _external=True)

  html = render_template(
    'email_confirmation.html',
    confirm_url=confirm_url)

  # Send account confirmation email
  mail.send_email(
    from_email='app@appdomain.com',
    to_email=user_email,
    subject='Confirm Your Email Address',
    text='Your account on AppName was successfully created. Please click the link below to confirm your email address and activate your account: '+confirm_url+'. If you have any problems email support@appdomain.com.'
  )
```

This is the confirmation endpoint:

```
@user_api.route('/confirm/<token>')
def confirm_email(token):
  try:
    confirm_serializer = URLSafeTimedSerializer(app.config['SECRET_KEY'])
    email = confirm_serializer.loads(token, salt='email-confirmation-salt', max_age=3600)
  except:
    flash('The confirmation link is invalid or has expired.', 'error')
    return redirect('http://localhost:3000/auth/login')

  user = UserModel.query.filter_by(email=email).first()

  if user.email_confirmed:
    return custom_response('Account already confirmed. Please login.', 200)
  else:
    user.email_confirmed = True
    user.email_confirmed_on = datetime.now()
    db.session.add(user)
    db.session.commit()

    return custom_response('Thank you for confirming your email address!', 200)
```

EDIT - Traceback:

```
File "/Users/derek/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-api-61-oxftK/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2463, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "/Users/derek/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-api-61-oxftK/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2449, in wsgi_app
response = self.handle_exception(e)
File "/Users/derek/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-api-61-oxftK/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_cors/extension.py", line 161, in wrapped_function
return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
File "/Users/derek/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-api-61-oxftK/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1866, in handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/Users/derek/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-api-61-oxftK/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
raise value
File "/Users/derek/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-api-61-oxftK/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2446, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "/Users/derek/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-api-61-oxftK/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1951, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "/Users/derek/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-api-61-oxftK/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_cors/extension.py", line 161, in wrapped_function
return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
File "/Users/derek/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-api-61-oxftK/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in handle_user_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/Users/derek/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-api-61-oxftK/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
raise value
File "/Users/derek/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-api-61-oxftK/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1949, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "/Users/derek/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-api-61-oxftK/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1935, in dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
File "/Users/derek/CodeRepos/App/app-api/src/users/users_api.py", line 198, in confirm_email
user = UserModel.query.filter_by(email=email).first()
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'email' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: Are you sure that is your real code? With what you have posted, `email` will always be defined - otherwise the code will return in the except block and the filter line will not be hit. Is the indentation correct?

Comment: Yup, it's the correct code. Only changes variables for the app name and email address when posing. Will check indentation again.

Comment: What do you mean, "changes variables"? Since variable names are the problem, you should post the actual ones.

Comment: Not the app variables (think I explained that wrong). Instead of putting ```derek@example.com``` i put ```app@appdomain.com`` and I used ```AppName``` instead of the real app name but this is only in the email content (nothing dynamic). All the variable that are used in the logic are the same.

Comment: I just changes the secret key in the config file and it works. Weird... Any idea what could have caused this?